# Laravel - files mimetype validation failing for some files with the same mime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

I've got two `mp3` files, let's say `file1.mp3` and `file2.mp3`. When I upload file1 it is successfully uploaded but not the same for file2 failing with a wrong mimetype validation. The string for validating the input is:

```
$rules['arquivos.*'] = 'required|mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,video/webm,video/mp4,audio/mpeg';
```

The html code for the form is:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class'=>'form-post']) !!}
<input class="novo-post-form-item form-post-file-input" name="arquivos[]" type="file" onchange="addNovoInputFile(this, {{ $configuracaos->num_max_arq_post }})">
// rest of the form
```

If I run the [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) and [mimetype](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mimetype) commands for both, it returns the EXACT same thing:

```
fabio@fabiopc:~$ mimetype ~/Music/file1.mp3 
/home/fabio/Music/file1.mp3: audio/mpeg

fabio@fabiopc:~$ mimetype ~/Music/file2.mp3 
/home/fabio/Music/file2.mp3: audio/mpeg

fabio@fabiopc:~$ file ~/Music/file1.mp3 
/home/fabio/Music/file1.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1,  64 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo

fabio@fabiopc:~$ file ~/Music/file2.mp3 
/home/fabio/Music/file2.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1,  64 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
```

So anyone knows what could be wrong this? Or it is a bug inside laravel validation part?

**Edit:** I've also found that this is also happening to some image files.

Comment: Can you run `php -r "echo mime_content_type('~/Music/file2.mp3');"` to just run through the mime type test in php?

Comment: they both output `audio/mpeg`

Comment: Strange, you might need to hook up a debugger to see where it's failing.  I highly recommend xdebug if you don't already use it.

Comment: it fails when I call the `validate($request, $rules)` function for the `file2` which is a function predefined by laravel

Comment: That's not nearly specific enough which is why I recommended a debugger.